# Choquet-Deny theorem

Tags: probability-theory, martingales

> Problem (*Choquet-Deny theorem*): Let $\sigma$ be a probability measure on $\mathbb R$, and let $f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be a
> bounded (Borel) measurable function. We will prove the $f$ satisfies the equation
> $$
>  f(x) =  \int_{\mathbb R} f(x + y)d\sigma(y), ∀x \in \mathbb R$$
> if and only if for each $x ∈\mathbb R, f(x + y) = f(x)$ for σ-almost all $y ∈ \mathbb R.$

> (a) Let $f$ be a solution to the convolution equation, and let $x ∈ \mathbb R$. Let $Y_n := x + X_1 +\dots + X_n$
> where the ${X_k}$ are i.i.d. random variables with distribution σ. Prove that $f(Y_n)$ is an
> uniformly integrable martingale (with respect to the natural filtration).

> b) Prove $\lim f(Y_n)=f(x)$ a.s 
> hint: Use Martingale convergence and the Hewitt-Savage zero-one law

**My attemps** 
in clause (a) I havn't managed to show it is a martingale, can I get a hint.
I tried showing 
 $E(f(Y_{n+1})|F_n)=f(Y_n)$ and $for \ A\in F_n:\ \ \ E(f(Y_n)*1_A)=E(f(Y_{n+1})*1_A)$

 but in both approach havn't gotten much progress.

In (b) I dont understand why would $\lim f(Y_n)$ be in $\mathcal E$ so i can use Hewitt-Savage zero-one law

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A set $A\in\mathcal F_n$ can be written as $(X_1,\dots,X_n)\in B$ for some $B\in\mathcal B(\mathbb R)$. Therefore, one has
$$
\mathbb E\left[f\left(Y_{n+1}\right)\mathbf{1}_A\right]=
\mathbb E\left[f\left(Y_n+X_{n+1}\right)\mathbf{1}_B(X_1,\dots,X_n)\right]
= \mathbb E\left[\int f\left(Y_n+y\right)\mathbf{1}_B(X_1,\dots,X_n)d\sigma(y)\right],
$$
where we used Funini's theorem and independence between $X_{n+1}$ and $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$. From the assumption on $f$, we derive that
$$
\mathbb E\left[f\left(Y_{n+1}\right)\mathbf{1}_A\right]=
\mathbb E\left[  f\left(Y_n \right)\mathbf{1}_A \right]
$$
which proves  the martingale property.

For the question (b), note that if you exchange the first say $10$ indexes, it will not affect $f(Y_n)$ for $n$ larger than $10$.